# DataStax Community: Inconsistent reads

Tags: cassandra, datastax, datastax-startup

We're using datastax-community-64bit_2.2.6 and DevCenter-1.4.1-win-x86 on a Windows Server 2012 (and same setup on an older Win Server 2008, that does NOT seem to experience the problem).

We have a time series table that is behaving VERY oddly with inconsistent reads. We have a full day of data, but data for some hours in the day is NOT loaded, when we perform queries - both through code and through DevCenter, as seen on the following screenshot:::

devcenter lookups::: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_e9YTMgramiSTFqUGFPYVB3bkk

As can be seen - the hour 7-8 cannot be loaded directly - as the hour from 9-10 can.
Loading just the hour 7-8 while using >= and < is possible (the top select), which just confuses matters even more.

In our application it gives a lot of the hours in the day as unknown (the icon with the ?) - as no data is loaded from Cassandra....see next screenshot::

missing hours in application::: http://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_e9YTMgramiTUxfNTlJYlVwUEU

The hours with a green icon are the same that we are able to query in DevCenter (as the hour 9-10 was on figure 2) - while the rest are not.
Making this even more cryptic is the fact that we load the same data for trend graphs where points for ALL hours are included.

Has anyone ever experienced anything like this??? ....it seems data for some hours are ALWAYS selectable from Cassandra, while others have issues :/
...and of course all data is inserted the same way!!

Comment: What you replication factor? What you consistency settings for write and read?

Comment: Hi Andrew, it's just a single node setup with SimpleStrategy, Replication Factor 1 and default consistency settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, when you query it by time range, you get the data back. When you query it by exact time match, you do not get the data for some timestamps. Correct? If it is correct, it is most likely you have got your timestamps recorded with precision higher than a second. Querying by exact timestamp match is almost never a good idea, unless you know exact timestamp value up to the required precision.

Comment: Of course!! - you're absolutely right, Andrew...so obvious :/ Thanks ;)